# How to generate all possible vectors based on sampling without replacement in R?

Tags: r, combinations

I have a pool of seven numbers. I would like to generate all vectors of length 7 with:

- two first elements are drawn from the pool of the 7 numbers.
- two next elements are drawn from the 5 numbers left.
- three final elements are drawn from the 3 numbers left.

That manner could be described by the vector c(2,2,3).

```
For example:
sample <- c(8.93,9.11,9.12,9.05,8.87,8.95,9.02)
structure <- c(2,2,3)
```

I know that there are 7C2*5C2*3C3 = 210 vectors like that. To be clearer I do not need permutation within each group of elements, for example, two vectors `c(8.93,9.11,9.12,9.05,8.87,8.95,9.02)` and `c(9.11,8.93,9.12,9.05,8.87,8.95,9.02)` are the same for me, I only need one of them appear on the list of 210 vectors.

Here is what I did using `for` loop, `combn` and `setdiff`. However, I would like to use the vector `structure` in the code and also make it more flexible, for example `c(2,5)` instead of `c(2,2,3)`. Is there any tidier solution to generalize my problem, with the `apply` function family for example?

```
df<-data.frame()
sample <- c(8.93,9.11,9.12,9.05,8.87,8.95,9.02)
combn(sample,2) -> com1
for (i in 1:ncol(com1)){
    com1[,i]
    setdiff(sample,com1[,i]) -> com2
    combn(com2,2) -> com3
    for (j in 1:ncol(com3)){
    setdiff(com2,com3[,j]) -> com4
    c(com1[,i],com3[,j],com4) -> de
    df <- rbind(df,de)
    }
}
df
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: @HectorHaffenden Thank you, I just update my questions with what I have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive version in base R:

```
x <- c(8.93,9.11,9.12,9.05,8.87,8.95,9.02)
k <- c(2, 2, 3)

f <- function(el, l) {
    if (length(l)==1L) {
        return(data.frame(t(el)))
    }

    do.call(rbind, combn(el, l[1L], 
        #using code directly from setdiff for slight speedup and 
        #comparing integers for robustness
        function(s) cbind(data.frame(t(s)), f(el[match(el, s, 0L) == 0L], l[-1L])),
        simplify=FALSE))
}

apply(f(seq_along(x), k), 1L:2L, function(i) x[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? Felt like a contradiction in the question with "I would like to generate all vectors of length 7", but then saying you only need one of the 2 eg's. Using `combn` wouldn't you just end with one random sample?

```
library(combinat)
x1 <- permn(sample[1:2])
x2 <- permn(sample[3:4])
x3 <- permn(sample[5:7])

all <- expand.grid(x1, x2, x3)
apply(all, 1, unlist)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just updated my question, I hope it becomes clearer now. I also included the code to get my expected result, but I still need a better way.

Answer (score 0):

```
find_combns_in_remainders <- function(list_combns_and_remainders, m) {
  unlist(lapply(
    list_combns_and_remainders,
    function(.) combn(x = .$remainder,
                      m = m,
                      FUN = function(combination) 
                        list(combination = c(.$combination, combination),
                             remainder = setdiff(.$remainder, combination)),
                      simplify = FALSE)
  ), recursive = FALSE)
}

Reduce(
  x = structure, 
  f = find_combns_in_remainders, 
  init = list(list(combination = numeric(0), remainder = sample))
)

# [[1]]
# [[1]]$combination
# [1] 8.93 9.11 9.12 9.05 8.87 8.95 9.02
# 
# [[1]]$remainder
# numeric(0)
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]]$combination
# [1] 8.93 9.11 9.12 8.87 9.05 8.95 9.02
# 
# [[2]]$remainder
# numeric(0)
# 
# 
# [[3]]
# [[3]]$combination
# [1] 8.93 9.11 9.12 8.95 9.05 8.87 9.02
# 
# [[3]]$remainder
# numeric(0)
# 
# 
# ....
# 
# 
# [[208]]
# [[208]]$combination
# [1] 8.95 9.02 9.12 9.05 8.93 9.11 8.87
# 
# [[208]]$remainder
# numeric(0)
# 
# 
# [[209]]
# [[209]]$combination
# [1] 8.95 9.02 9.12 8.87 8.93 9.11 9.05
# 
# [[209]]$remainder
# numeric(0)
# 
# 
# [[210]]
# [[210]]$combination
# [1] 8.95 9.02 9.05 8.87 8.93 9.11 9.12
# 
# [[210]]$remainder
# numeric(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention `combn` and `setdiff` here is a possibility:

1. We first create a convenience function `draw` that draws `ndraw` samples from `x` and stores results in `lst`.

   ```
   draw <- function(x, ndraw, lst) {
       unlist(lapply(lst, function(y) {
           lapply(
               combn(setdiff(x, y), ndraw, simplify = F),
               function(z) c(y, z))
       }), recursive = F)
   }
   ```
2. We can then define a function `generate_samples` to `draw` as many samples from `x` as there are entries in `draws`. I've added a check to ensure that the sum of `draws` equals the number of elements in `x`.

   ```
   generate_samples <- function(x, draws) {
       stopifnot(sum(draws) == length(x))
       res <- list(NULL)
       for (i in seq_along(draws)) res <- draw(x, draws[i], res)
       res
   }
   ```
3. In your particular case, we would do

   ```
   lst <- generate_samples(sample, draws = structure)
   #[[1]]
   #[1] 8.93 9.11 9.12 9.05 8.87 8.95 9.02
   #
   #[[2]]
   #[1] 8.93 9.11 9.12 8.87 9.05 8.95 9.02
   #
   #[[3]]
   #[1] 8.93 9.11 9.12 8.95 9.05 8.87 9.02
   #
   #[[4]]
   #[1] 8.93 9.11 9.12 9.02 9.05 8.87 8.95
   #
   #[[5]]
   #[1] 8.93 9.11 9.05 8.87 9.12 8.95 9.02
   #
   #[[6]]
   #[1] 8.93 9.11 9.05 8.95 9.12 8.87 9.02
   # ....
   ```
4. We confirm that this indeed produces `210` elements in the output `list`

   ```
   length(lst)
   #[1] 210
   ```